What does an ADC (add with carry) instruction following ADD do?
I have found this line in an old 16-bit DOS application (likely to have been generated by Borland Turbo C compiler) and I want to understand the purpose of it:
mov     dx, [bp+var_192]
mov     ax, [bp+var_194]
add     ax, 0FFFCh
adc     dx, 0FFFFh ; <-- here
push    dx
push    ax
push    ds
...               ; more pushes
call    SomeFunction

As far as I understand, the purpose of this "add with carry" instruction (in this particular case) is to set the carry flag to 1, but for whatever reason, it is not used. Is it a compiler optimization to set the carry flag to 1?
What I also don't understand is that dx register is not affected by this operation under debugger (e.g.: if it's equal to zero, it stays zero). I expected dx register to be decreased by 1 (since 0xFFFF is equal to −1).

add with carry really means add with carry bit, so it adds the two addends AND the value of the carry flag. So you can add 32-bit integers with just two operations (and easily you can have 64-bit and more)

I see. I assumed it means "add and set carry" but it's "add both operands and carry"

Yeah; in net FFFFFFFC is being added to the 32-bit quantity dx:ax.

@tigrou I'd assume it means both? Why would you do all this and not want to store the carry flag while you were at it.  Doing a 64-bit add in 4 16 bit instructions is pretty impressively efficient when it comes to dealing with a non-native word length.

@davolfman: It's far more common on the 8086 to use an ADD/ADC pair to perform 32-bit arithmetic than to chain more ADC operations to perform longer arithmetic.

just look at Intel's instruction reference which will explain DEST := DEST + SRC + CF;

@davolfman in 16-bit mode you can use 32-bit registers so you just need 2 instructions, for example add eax, ecx; adc edx, esi, to do 64-bit additions. And guess what, you can even do better with the x87 ST registers. Similarly in 32-bit mode you can also do 64-bit additions using MMX or SSE

@davolfman It means both, abut ADD sets the carry flag as well, so it is nothing special about ADC.

Why would you assume adc means “add and set carry” when you can already do that with add and then stc?

@Tommy: Which is the same as subtracting 4 from dx:ax.

@DrSheldon They could have even saved a byte or two by using sub / sbb instead of add / adc, taking advantage of a special encoding for unsigned 8-bit immediates.

@user3840170 Actually the special encoding is for a signed 8-bit immediate that gets sign extended to the width of the other operand, not an unsigned one.

@ecm Huh, so it is. I got misled by FreeDOS DEBUG, which didn’t use that encoding when I wrote adc dx, ffff. Now that I checked, adc dx, -1 does trigger it, and the former does as well in MS-DOS DEBUG.

Seriously though, how did it occur to @tigrou that adc is “add and set carry”? I don’t even mean this as a gotcha of some sort, I am genuinely interested in the thought process.

@user3840170 Indeed, my FD Debug/X fork lDebug (small L) also didn't optimise adc dx, FFFF to the imms8 encoding. Fixed now: https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/rev/4482d9e1b15b (The fix will be in today's current build at https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/old/ldebug/20240411.zip if you want to try it.)

@user3840170 being tired and not familiar with x86 code,  after seeing "add" and right below "adc" made me think one set carry and the other not.

As others have explained, ADC adds its two operands and the carry bit, storing the result in the first operand. Like ADD, it sets the carry bit as appropriate: adding two n-bit values produces a (n+1)-bit result, and the (n+1)th bit goes in the carry flag (counting from the least-significant bit).
So
add     ax, 0FFFCh
adc     dx, 0FFFFh

adds 0xFFFC to the value in AX, storing the result in AX and the carry bit, then adds 0xFFFF plus the carry bit to DX, storing the result in DX and the carry bit.
This allows additions to be performed on integers of arbitrary lengths. Along those lines, the two instructions above add 0xFFFFFFFC to the 32-bit value stored in DX:AX. While addition and subtraction don’t enforce this representation, it is common on x86; 16-bit multiplication stores its result in DX:AX, and 16-bit division applies to the dividend stored in DX:AX.
What you’re seeing in the debugger is essentially the result of adding 0x10000 (0xFFFF + 1) to DX: DX is unchanged, but the carry flag is set.

I guess the OP wonders why there are two add instructions. With just one (which must be ADC), one would need always and additional instruction to clear the carry first (CLC/ADC). with the addition of ADD, additions can start with ADD without clearing, continueing with ADC in case of multi word operation. So ADD is essentially CLC+ADC, while ADC is just the basic addition.

The 6502 has ADC and SBC, but no ADD nor SUB.  Many variations of the PIC architecture have ADD and SUB, but no ADC nor SBC.  Two-byte addition would generally use a conditionally-skipped increment for the upper byte.  Longer addition uses a trickier sequence of operations which ends up needing (4n-2) instructions total to add an n-byte number to another n-byte number when the destination is the same as one of the sources.

In other words, this is an addition of a 32-bit value stored in DX (most significant word) and AX (least significant) with 0xFFFFFFFC (i.e. subtracting 4 from that 32-bit number).

Further, on the 6502, SBC is implemented simply by inverting all the bits of the operand and then doing an ADC. This is why you need to set the carry before doing SBC so the combination of inverting the bits and adding one (the carry) is equivalent of taking the 2's complement.

add     ax, 0FFFCh
adc     dx, 0FFFFh ; <-- here

add ax,0FFFCh --> Adds ax and FFFC, if ax is at least 4 to start with it will
cause an overflow and set the carry flag.
adc dx, 0FFFFh --> Adds dx and FFFF and 1 if carry flag is set.   This has the effect of subtracting 1 from dx unless the flag was set by the previous operation.  It will also set the carry flag if dx is at least 1 or if the carry flag is set, but as you say it isn't used after this add.
The effect is something like this in pseudocode:
ax = ax + 0xFFFC;
carry_flag = ax > 0xFFFF ? 1 : 0;
ax = ax & 0xFFFF;
dx = carry_flag ? dx : dx - 1;

Adding 0xffff to a 16 bit register has the effect of subtracting 1 but also sets the carry flag if the value is non-zero.   If the carry flag is set when the operation is executed then an additional 1 is added and the carry flag will always be set then.

The original compiled c code was probably something like this :
long int somevar; SomeFunction(..., somevar-4, ...)
